# Generated IPA file is not getting the APNS push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Apple push notification is working fine while debugging. But when i generate IPA file and install on my device. Push notification is stop working. Device is unable to receive push notification.

Comment: Do you use the correct production mobileprovision / push cert?

Comment: When you run app on debug mode that time you have to send push using development certi & sandbox URL and when you are using app via ipa file installation that time you have to use production certi & remove sandbox keyword from URL.

Comment: Check your certificates for release mode in `build settings` and if all this good then please ask `server guy` to change configuration to `production` mode at his / her side.

Comment: thanks guys. I am using the development cert instead of distribution cert

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive Push only in Following cases

1) you device token is not valid for receiving the push notification.

2) Make sure you are using push notification enabled provisioning profile. and then check if you are sending token to server.

3) Check the entitlements while code signing the app. (They can be seen in Xcode build log).

4) You could check is if your device's date and time is properly set (in the OS). If your iPod, iPhone or iPad isn't set to the current date, we found that notifications are ignored silently. Of course, there are many other possible explanations as to why your service stopped working, but this is a simple thing to check when everything else appears to be fine.

5) In capability enable remote notification.

6) Set valid Provisional profile.

If above any not work then do as follow. I am sure work for you.

```
Go to Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles
Select my distribution profiles for the app in question, and delete them.
Go to developer.apple.com/iOS
Go to the distribution profile, modify it.
Just clicked "select all" (so I could re-save it with no changes), somehow the profile needed to be re-created AFTER enabling the Push certificate
Download the new profile and install it to xCode
Clean project under Product -> Clean
```

Also check sandox should be false. while sending push notification on distribution ipa, back end developer should not use sandox.